# How can I append an array of child nodes to a parent node in one operation using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, is there a way to add an array of child nodes to a parent node in one operation?

I want to do this in one operation to prevent unnecessary repaints.

I have tried parent `.appendChild(arrayOfNodes)`, but that gives an exception.

I am making a small component that will be reused among several projects, I don't want to depend on any library like jQuery or Zepto.

Comment: Just out of curiosity (unless it's a project constraint) why no **jQuery**?

Comment: I'm making an reusable compoent, and I can asume that that jQuery or Zepto is used in that project, so it have to be standard JavaScript

Answer (score 12):

You could use an intermediate `DocumentFragment`, which is a little convoluted but is likely to perform better than doing it a node at a time if you're appending newly-created nodes to an existing node within the document:

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfNodes.length; ++i) {
    frag.appendChild(arrayOfNodes[i]);
}
someElement.appendChild(frag);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll want to do someElement.appendChild(frag.cloneNode(true)). Not sure why, but that's what John Resig says, and I'm inclined to trust him.

Comment: @hobberwickey: I'm not, but I can't imagine he'd recommend that here anyway: there is no need to clone, and if there are event handlers on the nodes being inserted then inserting clones instead is definitely wrong.

Comment: @hobberwickey: The only reason to clone would be if you wanted insert several copies of the same set of nodes into the document, which is not required here. Resig's article is not clear on this point, unfortunately.

Answer (score 10):

With the ES6 spread operator a NodeList can be appended to an element in one line:

```js
parent.append(...children);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kind of old but I had a similar question. I decided to write a simple function which takes a parent (node) and children nodes (nodeList or array of nodes), not extending any prototypes or making it any more complicated than I thought it needed to be...

```
 function appendChildren(parent, children) {
     for (var i=0; i<children.length;i++) {
         child = children[i];
         parent.appendChild(child);
     }
     return parent;
 }
```

Comment: Just add this `Element.prototype.appendChildren = appendChildren;` and remove `parent` arg, it will be `this`

Answer (score 0):

You could add a method to [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node), which calls the appendChild method internally:

```
(function () {
  Node.prototype.appendChildren(arrayOfNodes) {
    var length = arrayOfNodes.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      this.appendChild(arrayOfNodes[i]);
    }
  }());
```

Which would then be useable like so:

```
node.appendChildren(arrayOfNodes)
```

Comment: `Node.prototype` does not exist in IE < 9.

Comment: Wouldnt this do multi re-renders?